# How to get current cursor position for Text widget

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I am using an onscreen keyboard to type data for a tkinter based gui.
I was able to use the entry field to enter, edit data through the onscreen keyboard such as getting current cursor position and length of the string.

```
temp = self.entry_label.get()
length_string=len(temp)
cursor_position = self.entry_label.index(INSERT)
```

But I wish to do the same for a Text widget. I could get the text for Text widget using `get()` method  and its length but cannot get the current mouse cursor position.

```
temp=self.new_text.get(1.0, END)
cursor_position = self.new_text.index(INSERT)
```

Acutally it works and i am able to add character to that poisition  , but after adding character  cursor goes back to origional position , i.e last character

Comment: You're showing code that gets the text index (`self.new_text.index(INSERT)`). Why do you think it's not working?

Answer (score 11):

maybe [This](https://www.daniweb.com/software-development/python/threads/105330/tkinter-text-cursor-pos-and-get-value-from-text) works? Else maybe `text_widget.index(Tkinter.INSERT)` is what should work.

Comment: Rather than just linking to an offsite resource, please also give the jist of the answer here. What happens if the site disappears?

Comment: @nephthyeswhite Please, just edit your question with something similar (that runs) from the website you are linking to.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thanks.

Comment: In case of `import tkinter as tk` do this:
`text_widget.index(tk.INSERT)` or you can just do this:
`text_widget.index('insert')`

Answer (score 0):

Although the other answer is correct and worked I believe tk.Current is the meta answer.

"tk.INSERT"

as provided by this reference.

https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/text-index.html

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).